# Generating a single queryset with filtered summary data across a foreign key?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a small Django project to learn with (it's a web UI for the RANCID backup software) and I've run into a problem.

The model for the app defines Devices, and DeviceGroups. Each Device is a member of a group and has a couple of state flags - Enabled, Successful - to indicate if they are operating correctly. Here's the relevant bits.

```
class DeviceGroup(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=60,unique=True)

class Device(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=60,unique=True)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    device_group = models.ForeignKey(DeviceGroup)    
    last_was_success = models.BooleanField(default=False,editable=False)
```

I have a summary table on the front 'dashboard' page, that shows a list of all the groups, and for each group, how many devices are in it. I'd like to also show the number of Active devices, and the number of failing (i.e. Not last_was_success) devices per-group. The plain device count is already available through the ForeignKey field.

This seems like the kind of thing that annotate is for, but not quite. And actually, I'm not sure how I'd do it with raw SQL either. Most likely as three queries and some lookup afterwards, or subqueries.

So - is it possible 'nicely' in Django? Or alternatively, how do you do the joining up again in the Template or View? The object passed into the template is simply:

```
device_groups = DeviceGroup.objects.order_by('group_name')
```

currently, and I don't think I can just add extra fields onto the queryset results "manually", can I? i.e. it's not a dict or similar.

Comment: [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) might be what you need. I'm not sure and never needed it so not gonna post an answer, but it might help you.

Comment: I think that would get me all the data, but no closer to a summary of it - 'count of related items that meet filter(x)' is the ultimate goal, not access to the items themselves.

Comment: I've given up for now, and just added a couple of IntegerFields to the DeviceGroup model, and a function to iterate through the Device objects at appropriate times.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must use

```
device_groups = DeviceGroup.objects.all().order_by('group_name')
```

or

```
device_groups = DeviceGroup.objects.filter(condition).order_by('group_name')
```

Comment: What is the condition though?